# Bootstrap datetimePicker months view

Tags: format, datetimepicker

I have integreated bootstrap datetimepicker on my website with some personalization.
The Problem is when i choose month format i have 3 rows with different number of months **4-5-3** i want to put every 4 month in one row. Any helps?

**JavaScript**

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var minDate = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth());

//init dateTimePicker
var params = {
  locale: 'fr',
  clear: "Clear",
  useCurrent: true,
  minDate: minDate,
  stepping: 5,
  format: 'MM/YYYY',
  icons: {
    previous: '',
    next: ''
  },
  inline: false
}
```

[screenshot of the timePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAAtX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h6>Datetimepicker</h6>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
  var currentDate = date.getDate();
  var currentYear = date.getFullYear();  
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'fr',
    clear: "Clear",
    useCurrent: true,
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
    stepping: 5,
    format: 'MM/YYYY',
    icons: {
      previous: '',
      next: ''
    }
  });
});
```

[**Demo on fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/6hjsre7y/2/)